# CodeIgniter not adding items into Cart

Tags: php, codeigniter, shopping-cart

So, I have This CI code, which for some reason, it doesn't add into the cart, but info side $data does prints out just fine.
Anybody has any idea what it's happening? It used to work just fine, and I have not touched this function in a while.
I do have an if statement to check that the parameters are set.

```
<?php
/* test data
$this->input->post('product_id') = 1
$this->input->post('name')       = 'ballons'
$this->input->post('qty')        = 10
$price                           = 9.99
$this->input->post('img')        = 'http://example.com/product_img.jpg'
$this->input->post('special_instructions') = 'long string explenation'
$this->input->post('options')    = array('color' => 'red')
*/
// set cart's info
$data = array(
'id'        => $this->input->post('product_id'),
'name'      => $this->input->post('name'),
'qty'       => $this->input->post('qty'),
'price'     => $price,
 'img'      => $this->input->post('img')
);

// check if special instructions are set
if($this->input->post('special_instructions'))
    $data['special_instructions'] = $this->input->post('special_instructions');

// check if options are available
if($this->input->post('options'))
    $data['options'] = array('type' => $this->input->post('options'));


// add data to cart
$this->cart->insert($data);

die(print_r($data).$this->cart->contents());
?>
```

Comment: you have the insert function for your cart object that you can paste?

Comment: Any errors? Show us cart->insert

Comment: no errors or anything, just no data gets added. I know the cart works, I have another function in which data is added manually, and that works, but this 1, where it's all automatic, it doesn't :(. I'm going crazy >.<

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're exceeding the 4K allocated to cookies. That's quite a lot of information to store in the cart. I suggest removing some of those fields from the cart session, and retrieving them from the database as and when you need them.

Comment: I tried removing info and leaving it with just the requirements, it still doesn't add items, but my other function works >.<